# Como volcar datos PHP y HTML sobre Imagen JPG (Llenar FORM)

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

Agradecere a quien se sirva indicarme como conseguir llenar un formulario (contenido en una imagen JPG, por tema de presentacion) a traves de PHP

La necesidad es llenar un formulario pre-establecido (.JPG) y generar un PDF, conteniendo el formulario lleno con datos obtenidos por calculos del programa

Aqui hay una libreria facilisima para crear PDF's, fpdm (http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php) pero cada vez que genero una plantilla PDF con campos (Adobe Acrobat) el PHP no lo reconoce y al parecer es condicion comprar su aplicacion pdftk (de pago), por ello se me ocurrio lo de "formatear" los datos sobre un JPG que contenga el formulario vacio. Agradecere plantear otra solucion mas viable y practica

Comment: Realmente parece una mala idea. ¿Por qué no sobre una tabla?

Comment: Es una forma un poco enrevesada, crea un formulario en php, lo rellenas y le das formato y luego lo conviertes en pdf, o aun más sencillo, lo muestras como tal sin necesidad de convertirlo en pdf utilizando el atributo onlyread para que no sean campos modificables.

Answer (score 1):

La solución más viable y práctica es mostrar el formulario en HTML normal y corriente. Una vez enviado y procesado el formulario, se puede mostrar un enlace para descargarlo, ya relleno, en PDF.

Aprende HTML y CSS para darle un aspecto lo más parecido al formulario PDF original. No es tan complicado.

Otra opción, menos viable y práctica, es mostrar en el formulario anterior:

- Un enlace para descargar el formulario en PDF. El archivo PDF tiene que ser de los que permiten rellenar los campos y guardarlo con los nuevos datos.
- Un botón para subir el PDF ya relleno. Tendrás que crear código PHP para leerlo, posiblemente tirando de alguna librería que permita extraer el valor de los campos (no sé si pdftk permite hacerlo o no).

Answer (score 1):

lo ideal seria algo parecido a lo que dice @jotaelesalinas:
la recomendación es la siguiente: presenta una tabla con inputs y de fondo le metes la imagen.

envías todo al servidor y de lado del servidor recreas la misma estructura, tabla con imagen de fondo, pero los inputs que recibes conviértelos en labels. por resultado convierte la estructura en el PDF de salida y tendras tu PDF con datos de formulario listo para imprimir.

desconozco si php/Librerias PDF puede recrear un PDF con Inputs incrustados que es lo que me parece que buscas.